# How to keep a matplotlib figure bigger than a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar

Good time of day.

I'm making a Python tkinter GUI that works with matplotlib. The thing is, my graph is rather large, and so I want it to be scrollable on a smaller canvas. For some reason, though, the figure either shrinks to the size of the canvas or the canvas matches the size of the figure, depending on what I try, and I can't find a way to combat this. Here's a code snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk

window=tk.Tk()
graphs=Figure(figsize=(6,12))
  ## The graphs I show here are random, I apologize if there are any mistakes
x=[1,2,3]; y=[1,4,9]
gr1 = graphs.add_subplot(311); rects = gr1.bar(x, y)
gr1.set_title('Title 1')
gr2= graphs.add_subplot(312); rects = gr2.bar(x,y)
gr2.set_title('Title 2')
gr3= graphs.add_subplot(313); rects = gr3.bar(x, y)
gr3.set_title('Title 3')

graphs.tight_layout()

frame3=tk.Frame(master=window)
tool=tk.Frame(master=window)
canv=tk.Frame(master=window,height=288)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graphs, master=canv)
canvas.draw()
vbar=tk.Scrollbar(master=canv, orient = 'vertical'); vbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')
vbar["command"] = canvas.get_tk_widget().yview
canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set,scrollregion=(0,0,432,864))
canvas.get_tk_widget().update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='x')
    
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, tool)
toolbar.update(); toolbar.pack()

canv.grid(row=0,sticky='NESW')
tool.grid(row=1)
frame3.grid(row=2)
window.mainloop()
```

I've tried setting the height into `canvas.get_tk_widget().config` and adding/removing `canvas.draw()` or `canvas.get_tk_widget().update()`, but nothing seems to work. I'm getting pretty desperate at this point. I've read on some resources about `canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))`,but it seems to refuse to work with get_tk_widgets. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is there a way to pass in `height`/`width` in `FigureCanvasTkAgg`?

Comment: @TheLizzard unfortunately not, that was my first thought also. It only takes `figure`, `master`, and `resize_callback`. That last one is a bit suspicious, but as far as I could understand, it refers to resizing the window.

Comment: A dirty approach would be putting the canvas in its own frame and using `<tkinter.Frame>.pack_propagate(False)` to stop it from expanding. Make use you specify the `height` and `width` of the frame.

Comment: @TheLizzard I played with this a bit - it first shows the canvas microscopic (picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AC5_OGnQ3GK3NyYfmcI_HFbQn_B0SwMu/view?usp=sharing), but if I change something on the toolbar (sunbplot config, for ex), It allows me to stretch the window and gives me exactly what I want. We're getting warmer - thank you for that, although I'm not calling "case closed" yet. :)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that you used to get that.